# What's wrong in my way to calculate $\int_0^a\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}\,dx$?

Tags: integration

I want to calculate this integral
$$
\int_0^a\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}\,dx.
$$

I did like:

Let $\frac xa = \sec(u)$

then $dx=a \sec(u) \tan(u)du$

When I do this, I recognize something wrong: That is, I can't make the interval of integral. 
The interval maybe from arcsec(1) to arcsec(0), but arcsec(0) is not defined. What is wrong and What should I do?

Comment: let your lower bound be arcsec(b), then take the limit of your result as b goes to 0

Comment: Since $\lvert \sec u\rvert \geqslant 1$ for real $u$, that substitution doesn't work. Set $x = a \sin u$ instead.

Comment: @DanielFischer Oh, I now understand what I did wrong. By the way, What is the number 3 on the left of your answer?

Comment: The number 3 (which probably will increase) is the number of upvotes for that comment. I've already put mine. I guess that comment is all you need to work on your own to succeed on this problem... If you "hover" the mouse to the left of a comment, an arrow will appear. Click it to upvote.

Comment: @mickep Thanks. How can I upvote the answer? I cant see anything to upvote the answer.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

$$\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}\space\text{d}x=\int\frac{1}{a\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{a^2}}}\space\text{d}x=\frac{1}{a}\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{a^2}}}\space\text{d}x=$$

---

Substitute $u=\frac{x}{a}$ and $\text{d}u=\frac{1}{a}\space\text{d}x$:

---

$$\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}\space\text{d}u=\arcsin\left(u\right)+\text{C}=\arcsin\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)+\text{C}=\arctan\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}\right)+\text{C}$$

---

---

Your definite integral:

$$\int_{0}^{a}\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}\space\text{d}x=\frac{\pi}{2}\space,\space a\in\mathbb{R^+}$$

Comment: I wonder what is the reason/purpose to include the last step to the arctan? It only means there will be (small) trouble inserting the bound $x=a$, right?

Comment: @mickep exactly!